# Is there any way to pass values from first activity to third activity DIRECTLY?

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I am a beginner. I have 3 activities, I want to send  data from 1st activity to 3rd activity directly.
I have used intent and shared preferences, but it only allows to pass data from 1st to 2nd activity.
Using intent also, we will have to provide 3rd activity name, but not by that.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please submit the code of all three activities so that we can assist better.

Comment: Activity 2 can forward/put all data from getIntent() to the intent to start activity3.

Comment: You need to show us some code and explain what isn't working.

Comment: Removed 'android-studio' tag

Answer (score 0):

set values in shared preferences using this function.

```
public static void setSharedPreferenceString(Context context, String key, String 
 value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
    context.getSharedPreferences("Your_app_name", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}
```

get values using this function in your third activity

```
     public static String getSharedPreferenceString(Context context, String key, 
     String defValue) {
     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
     context.getSharedPreferences("Your_app_name", 0);
     sharedPreferences.getString(key, defValue);
}
```